# Hide or show div based on children's content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

After trial and error with many solutions found on SO for hiding and displaying content using jquery based on textarea content I have ended up with a piece of script that *nearly* does what I want. I'm doing this in MVC 5, though I don't think that any consequence for this dilemma.

I have an edit page which has many optional text areas that can either be empty or have some text, these come from a database. What I wish to do is to hide them by default if they contain no text. They are grouped and they are toggleable with a click of the description text above them.

This is how I have them grouped, displaying one area:

```
    <div class="togglerDesc">
    <p class="pointerToggler"><strong>XXX description</strong></p>
        <div class="hiddenContainer">
            <div class="optionalArea">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1p1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Q1p1, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "2", @style = "width:90%;max-width:100%;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1p1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1p2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Q1p2, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "2", @style = "width:90%;max-width:100%;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1p2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q1p3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Q1p3, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "2", @style = "width:90%;max-width:100%;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q1p3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the script I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if (!$.trim($(".optionalArea textarea").val()).length < 1) {
            $(".optionalArea textarea").parents(".hiddenContainer").show();
        } 
});
```

Now this works just fine if the immediate text area, Q1p1 in my example has text in it. However if it is empty it does not show the div even if the two other textareas have text in them. It does seem my problem here is that the script is not taking all of the divs into account and only checks the first one. How could I change it so it takes all of the text areas within .optionalArea into account?

Comment: Couldn't you do this all server side and set some IsXSectionViewable boolean property of your view model then set display:none on that element in your razor if IsXSectionViewable.

Comment: @Fran I had not even thought to use razor, I had already done something very similar on other bits of the site so I thought to go down the jquery route despite being quite the rookie at it. Should no suitable answer using jquery surface up within couple days I'll follow your suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd second a server-side approach. Showing the div based on checkbox click is easy. All you need is to use whatever logic would set the initial state of the checkbox to also initially hide or show the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna need [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) because .val only takes the value from the first one

So something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".optionalArea textarea").each(function(){ // loops through all elements selected
        if (!$.trim($(this).val()).length < 1) {
             $(this).parents(".hiddenContainer").show();
             return false; // this breaks the loop as soon as 1 textarea has value
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I added an exclamation mark to `if ($.trim($(this).val()).length < 1)`  to reverse the logic. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem! Ah I missed the exclamation :) I'll update my answer as well if someone needs it in the future

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the call to .val() to combine the values from the 3 text areas?  That will not happen.  .val() will return the value from the first element selected, which is why you only get the desired behavior when Q1p1 has text in it.  You need to select all of your elements, call .val() on them individually, and then concatenate.

Comment: That would certainly explain the behaviour. I did try to fit in some each trickery into the script but I was unable to produce a working solution. Though I do not feel there is need to combine or concatenate, I simply chose to use .val() as many answers here on SO seemed to use that for checking empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure you don't have blank spaces or line-breaks alone on the textareas you can try with a simple selector match if it isn't empty:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".optionalArea textarea:not(:empty)").parents('.hiddenContainer').show()
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9r3b32tw/2/)

<sub>**Note:** An empty space or line break will take the element as with content.</sub>

---

With your actual code what you can do is something that allows you evaluate if any of the items has content like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".optionalArea textarea").filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).val())
  }).parents('.hiddenContainer').show()
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9r3b32tw/3/)

Comment: I actually had  `$(".optionalArea textarea:empty")` in one of my trials, however I did not realise you can use `not:`, very helpful to know thank you! Goes to show I really should dig into some javascript basics.

Comment: Glad to help a little more @Joonas the only about that is what I mention for blankspaces or breaklines, that's the advantage of the second solution and what you actually have the `trim`